# Proof involving weak and weak-* convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, duality-theorems

> *"Prove that if $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X'$ converges strongly in $X'$ and a sequence, $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X$ converges weakly in $X$, then, $f_n(x_n)\to f(x),\,n\to\infty$."*

My attempt:

Consider $$0\le|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|$$

$$=|f_n(x_n)-f(x)+f(x_n)-f(x_n)|$$

$$\le|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|$$

Taking the first expression on the last line, since $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X'$ converges strongly in $X'$ to say $f\in X'$ for all $x\in X$ this tends to zero.

For the second expression on the last line, since we know that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X$ converges weakly in $X$, to say $x\in X$, it follows that from the definition of weak convergence that, for all $f\in X'$, $f(x_n)\to f(x),\,n\to\infty$.

We than have that,

$$0\le|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\le0$$

And using the Sandwich Theorem, we can deduce that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\to0,\,n\to\infty$

Is this correct? I am unsure because in another proof on weak/weak-* convergence I had to use the fact that every weak/weak-* convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: What cbilz said. Depending on who you are it's appropriate or not to point out that of course your $0\le|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\le0$ is nonsense - that's not exactly what you meant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, but you have to use boundedness of $(x_n)$ to prove $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| \to 0$ in the following way:

$$
|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| = |(f_n-f)(x_n)| \leq \|f_n-f\|_{X'}\|x_n\|_X \to 0
$$

because $f_n \to f$ strongly and $(x_n)$ is bounded.

Comment: It is important to note that the uniform boundedness principle comes into game here. It is clear that *weak* convergence implies *weak* boundedness and thus *uniform* boundedness.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that $X$ is a Banach space and $X{^\prime }$ its dual.
The first expression in the last line can be estimated according to
\begin{equation*}
|<x_{n},f_{n}-f>|\leqslant \parallel x_{n}\parallel \parallel
f_{n}-f\parallel
\end{equation*}
It seems that here the boundedness of $\{\parallel x_{n}\parallel \}$ comes
in.